# JSON deserialization issue with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a json object like this

```
{ 
"id":23 ,
"key": "AKEY",
"description": {
    "plain": {
        "value": "This is an example",
        "representation": "plain"
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to map it to this object

```
   public class JsonResponse {
      private int id;
      private String key;
      private String name;
      private String type;
      private String description;

      /*usual getters and setters*/
}
```

I use the JSONSerialiser like this

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(responseEntity);
```

But how do I map the "description.plain.value" to "JsonResponse.description"?

Can this be done using jackson annotations?

thanks for your help

Comment: You should look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190350/custom-json-mapping-using-jackson

It seems to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I found this post [Binding JSON child object property into Java object field in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199794/binding-json-child-object-property-into-java-object-field-in-jackson) that partially solved my problem.

I wrote two setDescription() methods, one used by myself in my code, and one that's been called by jacskon

```
@JsonProperty(value = "description")
public void setDescription(Map<String, Map<String,String>> description) {
    this.description = description.get("plain").get("value");
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

It looks like the JsonProperty annotation is required to make jackson use the right setter.

Still I'm ok with this as long as it is a "short nested" property, but I guess Beri response is more acceptable with complex JSON responses.